# Como exportar valores de 3 colunas no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela com 129 colunas e mais de 400 registros, e devido a algumas alterações na estrutura, eu vou precisar refazer ela do zero. Mas eu gostaria de aproveitar o conteúdo referente a coluna1, coluna2 e coluna3.

Quando vou em "exportar" eu não vejo opção para definir quais colunas preciso salvar os valores.

Como eu posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o quer dizer com "exportar" mas você pode criar uma tabela auxiliar, cópia da tabela existente, e fazer: `INSERT INTO auxiliar(coluna1, coluna2, coluna3) (SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3 FROM sua_tabela)`, depois é só remover sua tabela antiga e renomear a auxiliar.

Comment: Hmmm, boa idéia em. Acho que vou fazer isso mesmo, vai ser bem prático. Muito obrigado manu :)))

Comment: a sugestão do@anonimo parece a melhor opição, só vou comentar pra sugerir que aproveite para modelar mesmo essa tabela, uma única tabela com 129 colunas é bizarro :)